# C# - Raw socket cannot capture outgoing UDP

Tags: c#, udp, raw-sockets

I'm using raw socket to capture incoming and outgoing UDP packet. My code is something like this:

```
public void Start() {
  if (m_Monitor == null) {
    try {
      m_Monitor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
      m_Monitor.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IP, 0));
      m_Monitor.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes((int)1), BitConverter.GetBytes((int)1));
      m_Monitor.BeginReceive(m_Buffer, 0, m_Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), null);
    } catch {
      m_Monitor = null;
      throw new SocketException();
    }
  }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar) {
  try {
    int received = m_Monitor.EndReceive(ar);
    try {
      if (m_Monitor != null) {
        byte[] packet = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(Buffer, 0, packet, 0, received);
        OnNewPacket(new Packet(packet));
      }
    } catch 
    {
    } // invalid packet; ignore

    m_Monitor.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), null);

  } catch {
    Stop();
  }
}
```

Incoming is ok but I cannot see any outgoing packet while Wireshark can (I'm using packet player to replay my old .pcap record). Firewall is off. Windows 10 1709.

Mostly it based on http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/pmon/

Any suggest? Thanks.

Comment: What language are you writing the code in? What frameworks (if any) are you using? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Editted. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. My problem was that my firewall was blocking the traffic. Try disabling your firewall and see if that resolves your issue. Tools like WireShark capture packets before they pass through your firewall. The issue is most likely your firewall is dropping the packets before the endpoint you are binded to reads them.